# Is the differential mean value theorem valid in this case?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $ f(x)\in R $

$$x=\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{bmatrix},\quad \widehat{x}=\begin{bmatrix}
\widehat{x}_1\\
\widehat{x}_2\\
\widehat{x}_3
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$x,\widehat{x}\in R^3$$

$$ f(x)=x_1^2 + x_2^2 x_3 $$

and
$$ f(\widehat{x})=(\widehat{x}_1^2 + \widehat{x}_2^2 \widehat{x}_3) $$

Now by differential mean value theorem

$$f(\widehat{x})-f(x)=f'(z)(\widehat{x}-x)$$

where
$$z\in R^3\text{ and }f'(z)=\begin{bmatrix}
2z_1 &
2z_2 z_3 &
z_2^2
\end{bmatrix}$$

Here, $x$ and $\widehat{x}$ vectors are changing with time and and $z$ is also adjusting according to that.

Now, my question if I replace $x_{3}$ and $\widehat{x}_{3}$ with some variable $y$

so, $ f(x)=x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}y$
and $f(\widehat{x})=(\widehat{x}_{1}^{2}+\widehat{x}_{2}^{2}y)$

Then, is the equations given below are valid??

$$f(\widehat{x},y)-f(x,y)=f'(z,y)(\widehat{x}-x)$$

where $f'(z,y)=\begin{bmatrix}
2z_{1} &
2z_{2}y & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Where did you get the zero on the third component?